# Jquery - Complex Selector of all inputs with an id containing a value with focusout not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Trying to have an event on the focusout of certain elements (rows of the table are dynamically added and looking to calculate the total of each row on the focus out of any field of that row)

```js
$('#modal-invoice-lines-list-tbody')
  .on('focusout', ':input [id*=rate],:input [id*=quantity],:input [id*=amount]', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var quantity = tr.find(':input [id*=quantity]').val();
    var rate = tr.find(':input [id*=rate]').val();
    var amount = tr.find(':input [id*=amount]').val();
    console.log(quantity + '*' + rate + "=" + amount);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="modal-invoice-lines-list-tbody">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="invoice_lines[0][description]" class="form-control" placeholder="Description"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="invoice_lines[0][quantity]" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="invoice_lines[0][rate]" class="form-control kt-inputmask decimal" placeholder="Rate"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="invoice_lines[0][amount]" class="form-control kt-inputmask decimal" placeholder="Amount"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Get rid of the spaces between `:input` and `[id*=`. Space in a selector means to look for a descendant element.

Comment: Thanks - so simple. Brain is mush! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: I'm just voting to close it as a typo. There's lots of similar questions.